# Why does nature allow parity non-conservation?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, field-theory, parity

The question is actually, how could a theory not respecting parity conservation be self-consistent? It is very hard to image that such an (apparently) imperfect theory be coherent and can go very far. I admit that I know only general physics and a little bit non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: You are just showing your prejudices.

Comment: I thought this was a nice talk on the subject.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elTJZroXPhw

Comment: Actually it allows it, and also allows particle antiparticle asymmetry which we observe. So it allows P and CP violations. But it does require CPT symmetry for a consistent theory, with T time, see my answer

Comment: It's hard to believe, yes, but seeing is believing - that's why we do experiments. In this case, the [Wu experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment) shows unambiguous evidence that parity is not conserved, and we just have to live with that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not that bad. It is known that the weak interactions violate parity conservation. That's why only left handed particles have a weak charge (i.e., participate in the weak interaction) and only right handed antiparticles do. It was a surprise when it was discovered, but the theory was able to catch up with it, suing so called Yang Mills non-Abelian quantum fields.  (Which also allowed for the unification of the electromagnetic and weak forces). The theory can be perfectly consistent with that parity violation. There's more (of the so called discrete symmetries) violations that are also consistent, and one conservation required for consistency. See below.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics) for parity violation.

The strong force may have some parity violation, but so far nothing. Otherwise it is believed that it conserves parity, just like the electromagnetic and gravitational forces.

Still, it turns out that there is another discrete symmetry, CP, that is charge conjugation followed by parity change, that is also not conserved in the weak force. See eg, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP

From that reference you can see that CP violation might be the reason, or a contributing reason, as to why the universe has more particles than antiparticles. Sakharov has proven that a violation of CP in the early moments of the universe is required to have the particle anti-particle asymmetry we easily see. But the CP weak violation appears to not be a big enough effect for the large particle-antiparticle asymmetry we see (about $10^9$ particles in the universe for every antiparticle). Thus there's a remaining issue, a big one, in physics, where the strong force needs to exhibit some strong CP violation. But we have not seen enough of it. It's called the strong CP problem. If those are not the reasons for the particle antiparticle asymmetry we cal only say that the universe began that way (more particles than antiparticles), and that's no explanation.

So, CP violation, and P violation, are in fact not a problem with consistency with the theory, basically with QFT, and the Standard Model of physics. We'd actually like more of the CP violation to explain the particle antiparticle symmetry, and it would still be consistent with the theory.

But it does turn out that there is a third symmetry, of the ones called discrete symmetries. It's time reversal, called T. It also turns out that CPT is a symmetry of nature, both from observations and from strong theoretical reasons. It has been shown and known, now for quite a while, that CPT is required in QFT (quantum field theory, the quantum mechanical theory of current physics), that CPT must be a symmetry unless the Lorentz symmetry is also broken (i.e. special relativity not true). Those two, are what is really needed for a consistent theory. Fortunately we have not seen any breaks in either one. Notice also, that since CPT is conserved, and CP is not, T must also have some small asymmetry. Again it is thought that's why the arrow of time points to the future and not the past, but it is still not known if that's enough of a reason for the arrow of time. It is believed that the initial conditions of the universe with a very small entropy probably defined that arrow of time, but nothing definitive either.

See CPT symmetry at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry

So, the theory is consistent, we just still have some missing pieces which makes people believe that there is some undiscovered physics Beyond the Standard Model